# How to check if new songs have been added: Android API 21 only

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat, audio-player, android-music-player

Reference:
In PlayMusic app as soon as a song is added the library is automatically updated even when the app is running.

How can the same be implemented for building a new music player app?

I am using MediaStore.Audio.Media to get the initial list of all the songs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing a Content Provider and can use it's API to register notification upon changes.

Use the [`ContentResolver.registerContentObserver()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html) method from activity, and supply the base Content URI for the provider and pass `true` for `notifyForDescendents` parameter, and your callback will get hit every time there's a change.

```
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(MediaStore.​Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, true, observer);
```

Pro tip: register and unregister in onResume() and onPause() respectively or you will get a crash if there are any changes while your app is not in the foreground.

Comment: getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, true, observer);

Can you also tell when should I unregister.

Answer (score -1):

- You can check with regular time interval set with timer for eg. after every 2 mins update the file for your media player.
- You can also manage during your lifecycle callback of onResume, onPause with a separate thread to check for any new added songs.

I would recommend second approach.

You can also check the source for default music player in android [Music player before android ICS](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_music)
Hope it helps: